# Xcode unable to create new "Window-based application" iphone app from template

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I'm trying to create a new "Window-based Application" in Xcode and I'm getting the following message:

```
Internal Error  
File: /SourceCache/DevToolsIDE/DevToolsIDE-1688/pbxinterface/Wizards.subproj/PBXWizardChooserWizard.m  
Line: 1365  
Object: <PBXProjectWizardChooserWizard:0x200b845e0>  
Method: sheetDidEndWithReturnCode:fileSystemLocations:contextInfo:  

wizard should be an instance inheriting from PBXProjectWizard, but it is nil
```

This only happens when I select the "Window-based Application" template, all the others are working fine.  When I'm on the New Project screen there's no description available for this template either.

I installed the new SDK for iOS4 yesterday and was having a few issues with files missing so I uninstalled and did a clean install to try and rectify but now I have this error.  Not sure if the two events are related.

If anyone has any suggestions as to how to fix this I'd be very appreciative! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out - just a little bug when selecting the product that the new project was to be developed for.  By default "iPhone" was selected, when I changed this to any of the other options "iPad" or "Universal" and then back to "iPhone" it seemed to fix itself.

Comment: did you find another way around this.

I am having the same problem, selecting iPad or universal app works but I don't want a universal or iPad app.

Any suggestions ...?

Comment: I changed it to 'iPad' or 'Universal', created a dummy project and then created another new one and it allowed me to select 'iPhone' no bother... hope you get it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

select the check box "Use Core Data for storage",then deselect it,then the description emerge,and you can create a window-based project now.